# Kafka brokers behavior after deleting a topic

Tags: apache-kafka, retention, amazon-msk

i'm new to kafka and figuring out its behavior.

I have a kafka cluster that has three brokers in it. I have given 2GB for the cluster and my cluster disk storage reached 95%. So what i did was deleted the main topic which i used for testing. (This topic has replication factor of 3, min in sync replicas as 2, 8 partitions and retention time of 3 days) Main reason i deleted this topic is i always used this topic and every test data was produced to this topic. My intention was to free up the disk storage.(I thought when i delete the topic, all the persisted message from that topic will get removed so that i will get more disk space from my kafka cluster) When i deleted i noticed two things.

1. One of the brokers disk usage went down. But other two brokers usage didn't change a bit.
2. When i listed the topics in the cluster, deleted topics had a note infront of them saying "Marked for deletion"

What is the reason for above behaviors ?

Btw i have set delete.topic.enable = true and auto create topic also true in properties of Kafka brokers.

Answer (score 2):

With only 2GB of storage, it sounds like you are hitting the storage limit. Kafka can get into a crash loop when it runs out of space for data, so even with the topics being marked for deletion because kafka keeps crashing it wont be able to make progress cleaning up the data to get to a good state.

You can increase your broker storage, and that should allow the kafka process to come up and be in a healthy state, at which point the topics should get deleted correctly.

[The best practices guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/bestpractices.html) mentions to scale storage at about 85%, this is to make sure your volumes can finish optimizing before you might need to scale again, and to leave some buffer space on the box.

Answer (score 0):

I think deleting a topic will not clear the disk space, if you deleted the topic, you can manually delete the index files and the data file of that topic partitions, but this is not a recommended way.

And I think the better solution is to update the [cleanup policy](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs_cleanup.policy) to `delete` and reduce the [retention time](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs_retention.ms) for the topic. Then Kafka will delete the data of the old [segments](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs_segment.bytes) older than that retention time for that topic. In this way, you can keep Kafka brokers clean from staled data.

If you need to keep the data on the disk, you have to change the cleanup policy to `compact` and it will compact the topic's old segments after the [delete retention time](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs_delete.retention.ms). It will keep the latest message for a key for a partition and tombstone older message for that message key.

Comment: thank you for the answer @nipuna. What is the reason for a topic to have "Marked for deletion" label when a topic deleted? And how long does it take to delete it permanently from the cluster ?

Comment: @Dushan The version of Kafka you are using probably uses Zookeeper. Data needs deleted from there as well. Kafka only reports "marked" until Zookeeper fully deletes the Znode. And, yes, data is indeed deleted from Kafka broker disks afterwards.

Comment: thank you @OneCricketeer . One last clarification, why does only one broker reduced in size instead of whole 3. I was expecting whole 3 brokers disk size would go down. But only one broker's disk size went down. Is it because of the replication factor or some other thing?

Comment: @Dushan All replicas should get deleted. Are the brokers actually healthy and running? Even with 95% disk full?

Comment: @OneCricketeer actually those are not running healthily. that's why i wanted to delete topics and free up some spaces. Since these topics are only for test purposes I'm deleting it.

Comment: @OneCricketeer So if a topic get deleted from kafka and zookeeper both, does the replica set also get deleted at that minute or does that replicas stay in brokers foe some time period ?

Comment: @Dushan Deletes are asynchronous, but will only be invoked by healthy brokers. You should be able to see server logs to know when segments really get deleted